# Issue while trying to onnect a horizontal slider to a LCD number and a progress bar in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to move the slider bar and the changing value to be displayed in the LCD number and a progress bar in Qt.
I use the connect function int the  mainWindow constructor as follows

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, ui->progressBar,&QProgressBar::setValue);
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, ui->lcdNumber, &QLCDNumber::display);
```

but the second function returns

```
error: no matching function for call to 'MainWindow::connect(QSlider*&, void (QAbstractSlider::*)(int), QLCDNumber*&, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

Why this happens ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Error happens due to parameter type mismatch. [QSlider::valueChanged(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractslider.html#valueChanged) has int parameter, [QProgressBar::setValue(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#value-prop) has `int` parameter too. So there is no problem between them. On the other hand [QLCD::display](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#display-2) has overloaded for 3 different types: `double`, `int`, `QString`. To connect overloaded signals/slots `QOverload` can be used:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, ui->lcdNumber, QOverload<int>::of(&QLCDNumber::display));
```

Another option is using lambda. We can fit both connections into a single lambda connection:

```
connect(ui->horizontalSlider, &QSlider::valueChanged, [&](int value) {
    ui->progressBar->setValue(value);
    ui->lcdNumber->display(value);
});
```

Old `SIGNAL()/SLOT()` syntax can also solve the problem. But I suggest to not to use them, cause they are error prone and "old".

Additionally check out [qOverload](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) which is `QOverload` wrapper for C++14.

Comment: Hi, I tried the SIGNAL()/SLOT() syntax for start since it seems easier but the valueChanged(int) and display(int) do not show up in the autocomplete for some reason.

Comment: Lol, I just realized [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots-syntaxes.html#selecting-overloaded-signals-and-slots) gives `QLCDNumber::display` example.